# Definite integral $\int_0^2 \sqrt{2x-x^2}\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How would you go about calculating the following definite integral? $$\int_0^2 \sqrt{2x-x^2}\,dx$$

Comment: is the ans = $$-pi$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

$$\int_0^2 \sqrt{2x-x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^2 \sqrt{1 - (x-1)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Now use a $x-1 = \sin \theta$ sub.

Comment: Okay I'll try that thanks! :D

Comment: Got it thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @user326441 great! Feel free to press the tick mark on the left of the post if you want to mark the question as answered. :-)